# TabControl doesn't load the tab content any time if switching the tab

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol

I use WPF MVVM and have a Binding in my TabControll like this (XAML):

```
<TabControl SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTabIndex, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, IsAsync=True}"
```

My Property looks like that:

```
private int _selectedTabIndex;
public int SelectedTabIndex
{
    get { return _selectedTabIndex; }
    set
    {
        if (TestbenchValidationCheck == true)
        {
            _selectedTabIndex = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedTabIndex");
        }
        else
        {
            _selectedTabIndex = 0;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedTabIndex");
        }
    }
}
```

If I switch the tab of the TabControll, then I don't see any content in the tab... if I change it more times and have luck, than I can see the tab content. What is the problem?

FYI:
If I delete the "IsAsync=true" attribute (in XAML code), then I am not able to switch the tab, i don't know why. Please note: I dont really want to use the IsAsync attribute, if there is another solution.

This is my OnPropertyChanged handler:

```
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
```

This is my Codebehind:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{


    public MainWindow(object obj)
    {
        DataContext = obj;
        InitializeComponent();
        SetBindingForCBXLists();
    }

    private void SetBindingForCBXLists()
    {
        var binding = new Binding();
        binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Element");
        binding.Source = DataContext;  
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(PortListBox, DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);

        var binding2 = new Binding();
        binding2.Path = new PropertyPath("Psc.CanTypes.Element");
        binding2.Source = DataContext;  
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(TypeListBox, DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSourceProperty, binding2);
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you verify the problem is not related to your `TestbenchValidationCheck`? Also, from the `IsAsync` [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.isasync(v=vs.110).aspx): "Use the IsAsync property when the get accessor of your binding source property might take a long time.", so you don't need to add that. Also could you confirm that your datacontext is set correctly.

Comment: I have to check the boolean variable before. If the variable is true, than it should switch the tab, if not, than it should not switch.

Comment: Then you'd just need a single if statement, without the else. Try something like `if (TestbenchValidationCheck == true) _selectedTabIndex = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedTabIndex");`

Comment: the result is the same. i cant see the content of the tab if i switch the tab and my Checkvariable is true. if it is false, then i cant switch (but this is a correct working)

Comment: @Fardey Do you see the content without binding for SelectedTabIndex?

Comment: @Rekshino: yes I do.

Comment: I think this is a synchronizing problem... but is there not a solution without the Async attribute?

Comment: You have to provide more code. The code you have posted do work.

Comment: @Rekshino: I have provide my Codebehind also.

Comment: What is your XAML. Why you don't set the bindings in XAML, but in code behind? What is content of TabControl? You need to provide a good Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example that reliably reproduces your problem.